# Is it possible to run Windows Defender offline in full scan mode?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I am testing Windows Defender in offline mode.
I set these two GPO entries

- Turn off realtime protection: Enabled
- Turn off routine remediation: Enabled

I placed a EICAR test virus in c:\ and started the offline scan with powershell (version 5) command "Start-MpWDOSScan".

The EICAR virus was not found (checking the event log). Same is true for an online quick scan.
Only an online full scan was able to find the test virus.

Seems the offline scan does an quick scan.

Is it possible to configure the offline scan to do an full scan ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way of customizing the Offline Scan.
In any case, by design this scan is different than Full Scan,
as the two are designed with different goals.

The Offline Scan is specifically designed to remove hard-to-detect and persistent types of viruses or malware from Windows, as
certain rootkit viruses have the ability to bypass the Windows Shell
and avoid being detected during regular Malware Scans.

Offline Scan works from outside the Windows Kernel, which allows it to
target Rootkit and other difficult viruses, including ones trying to
infect or overwrite the master boot record.

Offline Scan is supposed to be used only as a complement to Full Scan,
and to be only run after Full Scan has failed to eradicate the infection.
Therefore there is no point in Offline Scan repeating the scan that was
already done by Full Scan .